# What is the natural expression saying that we get some air in the mouth so that we could breathe under the water longer?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When people want to stay in water longer, they often open their mouths and store some air in the mouths so that they can breathe longer under water.

Is it natural to say "**take a sip of air so that you can breathe under the water longer**"?

Comment: You store air in your **lungs** so that you can stay under water for longer - you can't breathe under water!

Comment: A sip is a small quantity of water or some other fluid, not air. I doubt you could store enough air in your mouth to affect things for very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is [*to hold one's breath*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-hold-your-breath). You can say that the subject [*breathed in*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/breathe-in#:%7E:text=phrasal%20verb-,breathe%20in,nose%20or%20mouth%20synonym%20inhale), [*took a (deep/big) breath*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-a-breath) before holding it.